# Why `$input` can only be accessed once

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have a simple `test.ps1`:

```
Write-Host "access input for the 1st time: $input"
Write-Host "access input for the 2nd time: $input"
```

Then I do `'foo' | .\test.ps1`

Will output:

> access input for the 1st time: foo
> access input for the 2nd time:

After accessing `$input` once, the value is gone. Why?

[The doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#input) says it's because $input is an enumerator:

> Since $input is an enumerator, accessing any of its properties causes $input to no longer be available. You can store $input in another variable to reuse the $input properties.

But I don't understand what it means to be an enumerator.

As far as I know, if I pipe in a list of things, the list will not be enumerated because I don't have a `process{}` block. For instance if I do `@(1,2,3) | .\test.ps1`, my code will run only once, and the array is treated as a single object.

> access input for the 1st time: 1 2 3
> access input for the 2nd time:

So I don't understand what is being enumerated, and why $input is an enumerator.

Comment: Think outside PowerShell: You cannot rewind other commands’ output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the rest of what's in that that description and maybe check out [about_Functions_Advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.3) and [about_Functions_Advanced_Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.3).

Your example just doesn't make a lot of sense. Calling the script works it as an anonymous function. As you only let it use `$input` the first case is what happens:

> In a function without a begin, process, or end block, the $input variable enumerates the collection of all input to the function.

`Write-Host` accepts the enumerate and iterates it. Hence you seemingly only get a single value. Essentially it's calling ".toString()" on it.

Using a loop you will find that you do get individual values.

```
$counter = 0;
$input | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "access input for the $counter time: $_"
    $counter = $counter + 1
}
```

If you do need this functionality it would probably be better to make use of a process block. Check the advanced function help for more information on what that means.

```
begin {
    $counter = 0
}
process {
    Write-Host "access input for the $counter time: $_"
    $counter = $counter + 1
}
```

Keep in mind that in that case the way `$input` works changes slightly.

As per the [information about enumerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#using-enumerators) having regular function parameters with a suitable definition is usually perferable to directly working with `$input`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over a 'list of things' by piping the [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.3) over to a [`foreach-object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3) loop with the script/function call within its `scriptblock`.

Within that `scriptblock`, pipe the iterated value to the function call as [input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#input) to get the expected value per its returned output value per call.

This PowerShell solution has the script logic wrapped in a [simple function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.3#simple-functions) statement block, and you do not have to repeat the `Write-Output` code more than once—standard, easy, and basic.

Therefore, there's no need to be particularly concerned with respect to the `process{}` block.

#### PowerShell `Test.ps1` script

```
Function Test {
    Write-Output "Access to your mom's: $input"
    };
```

#### PowerShell [dot source](https://ss64.com/ps/source.html) script and call it

```
. "$Env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\test.ps1"
@("car","house","bank account") | % { $_ | test  }
```

#### Output

```
Access to your mom's: car
Access to your mom's: house
Access to your mom's: bank account
```

---

#### Logic breakdown

[image]

> But I don't understand what it means to be an enumerator.

**Furthermore, as per [`$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#input) statement** referenced and quoted below, this means it is going to be the placeholder for the input value passed as input so it enumerates that value passed. You use `$input` in the script, and it contains the value it received as input. The issue you were having is all values were passed as one long concatenated string per those methods.

- > Contains an enumerator that enumerates all input that's passed to a
  > function. The `$input` variable is available only to functions and
  > script blocks (which are unnamed functions).
  >
  > [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#input)

**Also**, that other statement you did not understand is just saying **it [`$input`] holds that value only in the instance which it is called**. You cannot use `$input` to get any value before or after the call, it is only set to a value as input on the call.

**Lastly, you can set a variable on a function call** to give you the output which `$input` "enumerated" on the call (i.e. `$var = "jewelry box" | test`). This means that variable is available outside of the call afterwards with the value `$input` was when it was executed.

#### Other potential bonus solutions

```
## Input piped to script function call
@("car","house","bank account").ForEach( {$_ | test} );

## Uses "$_" as the placeholder to contain the value iterated right to the command no script or function needed
@("car","house","bank account").ForEach( { Write-Output "Access to your mom's: $_" } );
```

---

## Supporting Resource

- [`.` (source or dot operator)](https://ss64.com/ps/source.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [ForEach Method](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-method.html)